# Database Designing for Friend Request

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, database-trigger

So, I am trying to implement something like Facebook Friend Request.

Let's say a User X receives friend request from User Y (uid: 1001) . If User X accepts the request, then User Y goes into `Friends_tbl`

So, in this case is the best idea is to store the requests into a table such as 
`friend_request` where the schema is

```
CREATE TABLE friend_request (
    request_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    from_uid INTEGER,
    is_accepted INTEGER
);
```

So, Let's say the first entry into database will be something as

`INSERT INTO friend_request(from_uid, is_accepted) VALUES (1001, 0);`

Now, when User X opens his friend request Inbox he will see a request from_uid 1001.

Now, considering two options:

1.) User X accepts the request. Then I will need to UPDATE the query to `friend_request` with `is_accepted` to 1 . And the hard part is if `is_accepted` would be 1. then I want to add that `from_uid` ito the `Friends_tbl` because now that guy would be User X friend's. How can I do that dynamically ?

2.) User X declines the request. Then what I should do ? Should I delete the entry into friend_request table so that it does not show's in User X Inbox or you have any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `friend_request` table:

```
CREATE TABLE friend_request (
  from_uid INTEGER,
  to_uid INTEGER -- add this column
  is_accepted INTEGER
);
```

For 1) you should do something like:

```
update friend_request 
  set is_accepted = 1
  where from_uid = <from-user-id>
    and to_uid = <to-user-id>;

insert into friends_tbl (id, friend_id) 
  values (<from-user-id>, <to-user-id>);
```

For 2) you may want to mark the request as rejected (value 2?):

```
update friend_request 
  set is_accepted = 2
  where from_uid = <from-user-id>
    and to_uid = <to-user-id>;
```

This way if the same guy want to friend you again, you can find out if it was already rejected, and don't even process the request again.

Comment: Note to the topicstarter @Adshead if you have a user table which iam assuming you have. You better can use a FOREIGN KEY. for both from_uid and to_uid columns like `FOREIGN KEY(from_uid) REFERENCES user(id)`. Documentation about foreign keys https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Dont code it like this use a status type of int instead against an Enum its messy to use isAccpeted like that way the friendship status could be anything in the enum easier to maintain

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni I agree. The only downside of enums (that I can think of) is that they are not easy to port to another database, should the need arises.

Comment: Why they can always be storeds as constants of int types